# How to calculate SMS length, size or number for non-english languages?

Tags: sms

Depending on the character table SMS length is variable. CiviCRM from 5.40 can count the number of character but for languages using diacritics the actual size will be calculate differently.

How can I easily check the really size of my message?

Comment: Also in 5.40+ the sms form in civi has a counter built-in, but it doesn't tell you anything special about non-english.

Comment: Guillaume - maybe you should rewrite the above as a question and the post your findings as an Answer

Comment: done Dave. Would there be a way to include such a tool in CiviCRM? it's a minor usage but still with big impact on costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful tool I've found on Twillio to check the length of a SMS, especially for non-English languages: https://twiliodeved.github.io/message-segment-calculator/

You can find [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-sms-character-limit) more information about the "logic" of the calculation. French `é` is considered as normal but `ê` or `ç` not :-( and this will split the message every 70 characters instead of 160! This will directly impact the cost of sending.